# Something that is true for every element of $\text{Sym}(\Bbb{N})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups, permutations

I'm trying to prove that:

> Every element of $\text{Sym}(\Bbb{N})$ can be written as $f\circ g$ for some $f,g\in \text{Sym}(\Bbb{N})$ with $f^2=g^2$.

But I can't even prove this for $\text{Sym}_n$. Any ideas?

Comment: What is $Sym \mathbb{N}$ and $Sym_n$?

Comment: yes they are symmetric groups

Comment: @dinosaur: I edited again but not sure what is `Sym_n` at last.

Comment: @BabakS. It is the permutation group of n elements

Comment: "But I can't even prove this for $Sym_n$." - No problem, since this property fails for finite symmetric groups.

Answer (score 4):

Hints: Write the permutation as a composite of disjoint cycles, some of which could have infinite length. It is then enough to solve the problem for the individual cycles.

Any cycle of length greater than $2$ is a composite of two elements of order $2$. For example, $(1,2,3,4,5) = f \circ g$ with $f=(2,5)(3,4)$, $g=(1,5)(2,4)$. This also applies to cycles of infinite length.

That just leaves cycles of length $2$, where we can take $f$ to be the cycle itself and $g$ the identity.

Comment: @user26857 By "solving the problem for the individual cycles", I meant solving it within the support of each cycle. i.e. for the cycle $(1,2,\ldots,,n)$, solving the problem in ${\rm Sym}(\{1,2,\ldots,n\})$. You can then just combine the solutions for the cycles to get a solution for the complete permutation.